# glReadPixels fills the buffer with black pixels in some Android devices

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, screenshot

I'm working on a Haxe game that builds to both Android and iOS, and just recently it's been noticed that a routine that was used to take screenshots of the game and use it to share to social networks has a very weird behavior. In some devices it works perfectly (especially in AVDs) but in some devices the code results in a solid black rectangle.

In summary, the code that reads the pixels from the frame buffer and saves them to a buffer that will be written to the new image, which I believe is some really standard fare:

```
                View rootView = Extension.mainView.getRootView();

                final int screenshotWidth = (int) (rootView.getWidth() * width);
                final int screenshotHeight = (int) (rootView.getHeight() * height);
                final int screenshotX = (int) (originX * rootView.getWidth());
                final int screenshotY = (int) ((1.0 - originY - height) * rootView.getHeight());

                // Create a buffer of pixels to have a copy of the screen
                ByteBuffer pixelsBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(screenshotWidth * screenshotHeight * 4);
                pixelsBuf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

                // Access OpenGL context to copy pixels into a buffer
                GLES20.glReadPixels(
                    screenshotX,
                    screenshotY,
                    screenshotWidth,
                    screenshotHeight,
                    GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelsBuf);

                // The pixels in the buffer are upside down, inverting only the columns of the image to gain performance
                int i = 0;
                byte[] tmp = new byte[screenshotWidth * 4];
                while (i++ < screenshotHeight / 2) {
                    pixelsBuf.get(tmp);
                    System.arraycopy(pixelsBuf.array(), pixelsBuf.limit() - pixelsBuf.position(), pixelsBuf.array(), pixelsBuf.position() - screenshotWidth * 4, screenshotWidth * 4);
                    System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, pixelsBuf.array(), pixelsBuf.limit() - pixelsBuf.position(), screenshotWidth * 4);
                }
                pixelsBuf.rewind();
```

I can confirm `pixelsBuf` is being correctly generating the image afterwards because I can insert pixels in it and they show up (over the black square) and is also already all black before going through the hassle of flipping it. What's really puzzling me is why the buffer is apparently empty in some devices and others not, and in what way we could guarantee that the buffer has the contents of the screen in any device (which I suppose is something that's implicit that we can make explicit, but I'm out of clues at the moment)

UPDATES: not sure if this will bump the question somehow, but more investigation was conducted and it's not very promising.

Using glGetIntegerv to query OpenGL properties in the system tells me that, at least in theory, the value for COLOR_READ_FORMAT and COLOR_READ_TYPE are correct. Using the same values that GLES20 return into glReadPixels works in the same devices and gives a black screen in the same devices; so it seems not to be a configuration problem.

Doing a random sample of the pixel buffer after flipping the pixels also shows that any random pixel in the black image is actually [0,0,0,255]; it is not transparent, it's actually just reading black.

Investigation is proceeding in the direction of finding perhaps another buffer where the screen pixels might be instead of the default glReadPixels is reading from. Otherwise... I'm completely lost.

Comment: Check it's not just transparent.

Comment: ByteOrder.nativeOrder() - Retrieves the native byte order of the underlying platform. Could it be the case that for some devices native order is not LITTLE_ENDIAN?

Comment: @solidpixel I tried setting the alpha byte for every pixel in the buffer to 255, confirmed it worked normally in the simulator but still got a black screen in the Motorola G20

Comment: @Hihikomori if that's the case I would expect the colors to be all mixed up but still something other than just black pixels, no?

Comment: Let say the pixel format is not GLES20.GL_RGBA_8888 by default for Motorola G20.

Comment: Is it definitely being called from a thread with an eglContext bound? any error from glGetError?

Comment: @solidpixel I should have mentioned that, no, there's no error code; running glGetError after the whole process just gets me a result of 0

Comment: @Hihikomori not sure if I understand, I tried querying the GLES library for the values of read format and read type and they are coming up  as GL_RGBA and GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE even in the device where the screenshot is coming up black